# How to skin Alert box in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, alert, skinning

How do I skin alert box in flex 4?
I am not interested in customizing alert box via css, how do I create skin?

For example, for `TextInput` I would write in css:

```
s|TextInput
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.TextInputSkin");
}
```

and in TextInputSkin.mxml

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" 
    alpha.disabledStates="0.5" blendMode="normal">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.TextInput")]  
        ...etc..
```

And get TextInput globally changed.
How do I make something similar for `Alert`?  I can't understand what is host component for alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mx.controls.Alert](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html) control is an MX component, and for that reason doesn't use the same skinning architecture that Spark components use, which is what your example uses.  Frankly, even though Adobe still refers to it as "skinning" (cf., [Skinning MX Components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fed.html)), it doesn't seem to resemble the Spark process very much.

I'm not claiming to offer a comprehensive answer (which is why I'm community wiki-ing this), but as far as I can tell, you're not going get around using styles.

The other relevant information you'll probably need to know is that the Alert derives from the [mx.containers.Panel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Panel.html) class.  So to whatever extent you can "skin" a Panel, is the extent to which you're ultimately going to be able to "skin" an Alert.

Comment: Makes sense, anyway I made my custom component alert.

Answer (score 2):

The MX Alert component is not a single control so to speak. It is basically a combination of the panel, label and button components. Try this out, Skin/Style a standard MX Panel component and apply it globally to your application, You will notice that when you try to call the alert component, it is also affected as it would take the form of the style you just applied. You can Skin a Flex 4 panel then make it a custom popup component to achieve the same effect.